# How to check if given time (in UTC) is max.10 minutes time frame

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I have a time string and moment to parse like this:

```
const d: string = '2019-05-30T00:05:46.987Z'
const date: Date = moment.utc(d)
```

What I want is to check this time if its in **max. 10 min. old**. If its more than 10 minutes then `false` should given. I want to do this checking against `UTC` and not the timezone by browser/user.

How can I do that?

I am trying to determine if given object and its time is fresh or not.

Comment: But that question talks about array source and filtering. Mine is string.

Comment: Ah got it answer shows isAfter usage.